# Qual a forma correta de simular um <script> com uma linguagem nova?

Tags: javascript, html

Suponha que implementei uma nova linguagem e que tenho um interpretador funcional escrito em javascript. Algo como `mylang.interpret(code_as_string)`. Agora gostaria de criar uma interface na qual eu posso inserir o código da minha linguagem em tags `<script>` de forma que ele funcione exatamente igual a como o javascript opera. Ou seja:

```html
<script src="mylang.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- o interpretador -->

<script type="text/mylang">
    global a = 5;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(mylang.globals.a); // deve mostrar 5
</script>
<script type="text/mylang">
    a = 6;
</script>
```

Ou seja, as tags `<script>` seria executada sequencialmente e poderia intercalar com o javascript. Sei que posso por um evento no `onload` para executar todos os scripts com a minha linguagem (já que eles são ignorados pelo navegador), mas isso não teria o comportamento que espero do exemplo acima. Outro caso é se o elemento for inserido via javascript. Existe como ter um callback que seja chamado sempre que um elemento aparecer no DOM?

Outro problema é com o carregamento se a tag vier com o atributo `src`. Imaginei em carregar via ajax, mas com isso os scripts serão executados fora de ordem, e não estritamente na ordem em que aparecem. Como garantir essa ordem?

Comment: Cara, que pergunta bacana! Eu não acho que consiga responder, mas já me ocorreram algumas questões aqui. Se você usar a tag "script" não vai dar confusão no navegador? Talvez você precise criar a sua própria tag e acessar elementos dela via DOM para interpretar. Já tentou algo nessa linha?

Comment: Oops. Vi só agora na sua pergunta que eles são ignorados pelo navegador. Verdade. Sorry. :)

Comment: @Luiz Empiricamente notei que se eu usar um `type` que não existe, o `<script>` vira um noop. Mas não sei até onde isso é verdade. Sobre criar uma tag nova, vai cair nos mesmos problemas que eu citei, não? Meu objetivo é ter esse funcionamento tão transparente quanto possível

Comment: Sim. A questão é a ordem, principalmente a intercalação com Javascript.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal respondi ali. Se for mais ou menos isso que você quer, eu adiciono código que implementa isso pra você. Só não vou fazer um interpretador inteiro de linguagem porque daí já é forçar a amizade. Aliás, parabéns pela pergunta. Vai +1 Fav

Comment: Alguém já tentou algo muito parecido com o que você quer fazer. Veja o artigo abaixo: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/custom-javascript-with-parsescripts/

Comment: +1 pela pergunta interessante.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Esta não chega a ser uma resposta direta pois não envolve um *callback* nativo, porém, consigo pensar que uma solução seria a criação de um *loader* capaz de carregar e processar dinamicamente o código da página, exatamente como o PHP faz, por exemplo.

O *loader* seria um interpretador escrito em JavaScript capaz de carregar um código-fonte, iniciando a leitura em "modo html". Ao encontrar uma tag `<script>`, ele passaria a executar o respectivo código, dependendo da linguagem. No caso de JavaScript, poderia delegar ao próprio navegador.

Enfim, adicionando algumas restrições ao modo como a página é carregada, em tese parece ser possível.

---

### Update: executando Python juntamente com Javascript no navegador

Baseado no excelente achado do **@bfavaretto**, o `MutationObserver`, criei um pequeno projeto para executar Python lado-a-lado com Javascript uma página.

Primeiro baixei o [**Brython**](http://www.brython.info/), uma implementação do Python 3 em Javascript para execução no navegador.

Depois, montei uma classe baseada no código do @bfavaretto.

#### `pyscript.js`

```js
//inicializa brython
brython();

// Cria objeto que vai monitorar alterações no DOM
function criaObserver(el) {
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        // Loop sobre as mutações detectadas
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {

            // Inserção de nós aparecem em addedNodes
            var node = mutation.addedNodes[0];

            // Achou um script
            if(node && node.tagName === 'SCRIPT' && node.type === 'text/pyscript') {
                console.log('encontrado pyscript')
                var $src;
                if(node.src!=='') {
                    // get source code by an Ajax call
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                       var $xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }else{// code for IE6, IE5
                       var $xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    $xmlhttp.open('GET',node.src,false)
                    $xmlhttp.send()

                    if($xmlhttp.readyState===4 && $xmlhttp.status===200){
                        $src = $xmlhttp.responseText
                    }
                    if ($src === undefined) { // houston, we have a problem!!!
                        console.log('erro ao carregar script')
                        return;
                     }
                } else {
                    $src = node.textContent || node.innerText;
                }

                // ver https://bitbucket.org/olemis/brython/src/bafb482fb6ad42d6ffd2123905627148e339b5ce/src/py2js.js?at=default

                // Passa o código para ser interpretado
                __BRYTHON__.$py_module_path['__main__'] = window.location.href;
                var $root=__BRYTHON__.py2js($src,'__main__');
                $src = $root.to_js();

                // eval in global scope
                if (window.execScript) {
                   window.execScript($src);
                   return;
                }

                var fn = function() {
                    window.eval.call(window,$src);
                };
                fn();
            } 
        });    
    });

    // Inicia o observer, configurando-o para monitorar inserções de nós em qualquer nível
    observer.observe(el, { childList: true, subtree: true })
    return observer; 
}

var observer = criaObserver(document);
```

Finalmente, fui capaz de executar com sucesso o código da página abaixo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Python Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="brython.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pyscript.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var variavel = 1;
</script>

<script type="text/pyscript">
print('teste de print!')
print(variavel)
</script>

</head>

<body>
   <div id="content">Conteúdo</div>
</body>

<script type="text/pyscript">
from _browser import doc, alert
alert('Valor da variável: ' + str(variavel))

lista = ['itens', 'da', 'lista']
doc['content'].text = 'Conteúdo colocado com python: ' + ' '.join(lista)
</script>

<script type="text/pyscript" src="teste.js"></script>

</html>
```

Note que existe a inclusão de um arquivo externo (`teste.js`), contendo o código python a seguir:

```py
d = { '11': 'um', '22': 'dois' }
for i in d:
    print(i)
```

Por um lado, existe uma limitação dessa solução, derivada de uma limitação do Brython: o código Javascript não consegue acessar os objetos criados dentro de um trecho Python.

Entretanto, como visto no exemplo, fazer o inverso é simples e direto, isto é, o código Python tem total acesso ao código Javascript.

### [Exemplo funcional na minha conta do GitHub](http://utluiz.github.io/pyscript/index.html)

Comment: Ou seja, transformar a página inteira em uma string e interpretar o HTML todo? Isso me dá calafrios. É, funcionaria.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Vou pra casa, descansar... quem sabe eu não sonho com uma solução melhor! rsrs

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Minha "solução" pode incorrer em muitos problemas de contexto de javascript. Calafrios²!

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Dá uma olhada nessa resposta do SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2872454/2896619 O autor cita alguns outros exemplos de scripts. Talvez se vc fuçar neles descubra como fazem. :)

Comment: Em relação a colocar um listener para novo objeto DOM vc pode usar [`MutationObserver`](http://caniuse.com/mutationobserver) tem um exemplo em [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn254985(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Perfeito! Parece cumprir todos os requisitos que eu tinha em mente, estava prestes a postar uma implementação similar baseada no bfavaretto, mas você o fez mais rápido. Falaram de problema de performance, mas de qualquer forma o gargalo será o interpretador. Agora posso ir dormir em paz sabendo que não terei que processar html :)

Answer (score 8):

É possível monitorar o carregamento do DOM utilizando um [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Ainda há restrições de suporte quanto ao uso disso (por exemplo, no IE, só foi implementado na versão 11), e não tenho informações sobre performance. No entanto, como prova de conceito, construí um código que localiza os blocos de script e passa ao interpretador. É possível inclusive obter o código-fonte de arquivos externos de maneira síncrona, usando XMLHttpRequest.

Aqui vai o coração do código, a ser colocado antes de qualquer outro script:

```
// Cria objeto que vai monitorar alterações no DOM
function criaObserver(el) {
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        // Loop sobre as mutações detectadas
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {

            // Inserção de nós aparecem em addedNodes
            var node = mutation.addedNodes[0];

            // Achou um script
            if(node.tagName === 'SCRIPT' && node.type === 'text/fooscript') {

                // TODO: implementar chamada ajax síncrona (argh!) para pegar o código
                if(node.src) {

                }

                // Passa o código para ser interpretado
                interpreta(node.textContent || node.innerText);
            } 
        });    
    });

    // Inicia o observer, configurando-o para monitorar inserções de nós em qualquer nível
    observer.observe(el, { childList: true, subtree: true })
    return observer; 
}

var observer = criaObserver(document);
```

Ao final do carregamento do DOM (ou seja, no final do `body`, no evento `DOMContentReady`, ou, em último caso, no `window.onload`), é preciso desconectar o observer:

```
observer.disconnect();
```

Veja um [demo no jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vazax/2/edit).

Comment: Não conhecia o `MutationObserver`. Experimentarei mais tarde. Fantástico!

Comment: Um dos motivos de eu ter feito com o `window.onload` simples é que mesmo se tivesse um jeito de interpretar elementos externos enquanto fossem carregados, teria que travar toda a renderização da página unicamente por causa disso, da mesma forma como ocorre com javascript hoje. Porém diferente de js nativo, não sei se é possível forçar até mesmo navegadores modernos a parar de carregar a DOM pra aguardar o script remoto sem por um loop que torraria CPU. Tem como por em sleep toda criação da página (JS, CSS, HTML) sem fritar CPU?

Comment: @EmersonRochaLuiz Pelos meus testes, *parece* que o callback do MutationObserver é executado de forma síncrona. Para pegar scripts remotos, é possível fazer um XMLHttpRequest síncrono. Não que eu recomende qualquer um desses métodos...

Comment: Ignore comentário anterior quanto a não ser possível carregar arquivo js externo de forma síncrona. Vi agora que tem com um parametro do `XMLHttpRequest`. Nunca tinha usado isso antes.

Comment: @EmersonRochaLuiz Sorte sua! :) Isso é altamente contra-indicado

Comment: Usar Ajax pra fazer requisição síncrona antes do carregamento da página (usando o MutationObserver) é meio que gasto desnecessário de recurso (é melhor já embutir o script na página). Agora se for trazer o script assíncrono você pode usar o onreadystatechange.

Comment: --Edit acabei de achar esse link [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.ilinsky.com/articles/XMLHttpRequest/)

Comment: @LeandroAmorim Embutir como? No corpo do HTML mesmo? A pergunta fala do uso do atributo `src`, e para funcionar como js precisaria fazer uma requisição dessas.

Comment: @bfavaretto mas src iria enquadrar perfeitamente no seu script. Pq o onload só é chamado depois que a "pagina toda" é carregada, inclusive os scripts com src, pode ser que eu não tenha entendido a necessidade de fazer um "XMLHttpRequest" síncrono antes do onload, mas isso me parece um uso esquisito para o "XMLHttpRequest". Quando digo embutir seria isso mesmo ou colocar no corpo html ou colocar um src.

Comment: @LeandroAmorim O src só funciona se o `<script>` não tiver `type`, ou se for um type válido de js. Aí o browser baixa e interpreta como js. A intenção da pergunta é tratar como outra linguagem.

Answer (score 4):

Esse é o principio de interpretadores `LESS` e outros que usam um type que não existe e então é ignorado pelo navegador.

Aqui o passo a passo

1. Usar `<script>` com um `type` que não existe
2. Adicionar seu processador de linguagem, que usará javascript para primeiro procurar todas as tags script, por exemplo `document.querySelectorAll('script')`, e então para cada uma delas, irá testar se o type é o desejado
3. Para cada script com seu type encontrado, dar um `innerHTML`/`innerText`/`textContent` para obter uma string com o que há dentro dele
4. Para cada string obtida, processe ela com seu interpretador em javascript

Isso é bem legal. Tecnicamente seria possível até fazer interpretador de outras linguagens dentro de um navegador só usando javascript

### Prova de conceito

Segue PoC. Se fizer o interpretador eu implemento ele aqui. Dê uma olhada. É uma coisa meio apelativa querer que seu interpretador seja compreendido ao mesmo tempo que o parser de Javascript, até tem como, mas não fiz isso, então da forma como fiz seu parser só vai ficar ativo em `onload`

**HTML de exemplo**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="mylang.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!-- o interpretador -->

    <script type="text/mylang">
      global a = 5;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //alert(mylang.globals.a); // deve mostrar 5
    </script>
    <script type="text/mylang">
      a = 6;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // lalala
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**mylang.js**

```
var mylang = {};
mylang.globals = {};
mylang._scripts_all = []; // Todos os scripts
mylang._scripts_ml = []; // Somente os "text/mylang"
window.onload = function () {
    var i;
    function interpretador (string) {

        //@todo kung-fu aqui
        mylang.globals.a = null;
        console.log('kung-fu ',  string);
    }

    mylang._scripts_all = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('script'));
    mylang._scripts_ml = [];

    for (i = 0; i < mylang._scripts_all.length; i += 1) {
        if (mylang._scripts_all[i].type && mylang._scripts_all[i].type === "text/mylang") {

            mylang._scripts_ml.push(mylang._scripts_all[i]);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < mylang._scripts_ml.length; i += 1) {
        interpretador(mylang._scripts_ml[i].innerHTML);
    }
};

// Console imprime
//kung-fu  
//      global a = 5;
//     mylang.js:11
//kung-fu  
//      a = 6;
```

PS.: Isso não é algo trivial. Espero que se estiver mesmo correto, o pessoal valorize ;P

Comment: Embora não atenda a todos os requisitos da pergunta, acho uma boa solução.

Comment: Mas como operar estritamente em ordem quando intercalado com javascript? Assim tudo será executado apenas depois de outros scripts de javascript.

Comment: Vocês estão falando em _criar um interpretador em tempo real dentro de um navegador_. Tem como atender praticamente todos os requisitos do Guilherme, alguns só não vão ter performance muito boa. Executem meu código removendo de dentro do `window.onload` e reparem que as tags seguintes ainda não vão estar prontas. Para atender o requisito do Guilherme, a única coisa que faltaria para isso é ler qual listener é ativado toda vez que o HTML está sendo parseado e interpretado e executar scripts que forem da linguagem. No meu PoC por simplicidade fiz considerando com `onload`

Comment: @EmersonRochaLuiz Sim, dá para fazer isso com MutationObserver, mas tenho dúvidas quanto a suporte e performance.

Comment: Então, dai vai do levantamento de requisitos do Guilherme. `window.onload` faria um interpretador em javascript parrudo de C++ funcionar bem até no IE5. http://caniuse.com/mutationobserver não tem suporte tão bom, então precisaria ver todo um código só pra fazer funcionar. Reforço, o problema não é ser executado em ordem, **a quantidade adicional de código seria pra executar em ordem intercalando  "text/mylang" com javascript tradicional**. Isso é que impacta performance e muito código adicional

Answer (score 2):

Para que isso funcione da forma que você pediu, seu interpretador não deve executar seu script.
Explico: Dada a seguinte `script tag`:

```
<script type="text/rubysh">
    def teste
        puts "olá"
    end
</script>
```

O script do tipo `text/rubysh` teria de ser então traduzido para `text/javascript`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function teste(){
        console.log("olá");
    }
</script>
```

O seu interpretador/compilador então iria subustituindo as tags originais pelas do tipo `text/javascript` **antes** de tudo ser executado.
E então deixar o navegador executar tudo normalmente.

...
Outra solução seria fazer script com type "text/javascript" e chamar uma função `eval` do seu interpretador passando os comandos como string... o que fica bem feio (eval is evil)

Comment: Antes de tudo ser executado? Isso é antes do interpretador ser carregado. E ainda assim só tenho acesso às tags que já foram inseridas no DOM. Além disso as tags de script são imediatamente executadas ao serem inseridas, o que quebra a ordem de execução pretendida.

Comment: Não, digo, o interpretador deve ser executado antes das outras tags.
Nem que ele tenha que remover as tags script e adicionar em um array pra devolver todas as scripts de novo na ordem certa (interpretando as que são relevantes).

Comment: Se o interpretador é executado antes, então as outras tags script não estão nem mesmo no DOM ainda e não tenho como ler elas

Comment: hmm...
não tinha pensado nisso. Isso derruba minha resposta toda...

Seu interpretador tem mesmo que ser client side? No server side isso não seria um problema (seria um pre-processador que escreveria javascript). Ou ainda você poderia mudar o type dos javascripts para eles não executarem, mas é "xunxo", não gosto dessa opção.