# Como criar um simples interpretador?

Tags: independente-de-linguagem, interpretador

Sempre tive vontade de criar uma linguagem (algo simples) para mim mesmo mas não tenho ideia de como.
A pergunta é: Como criar um simples interpretador ?

Comment: Essa pergunta me parece ampla demais. Você quer uma visão geral dos passos necessários pra se criar um interpretador? Ou sua dúvida é em uma etapa mais específica? (tipo, como fazer a análise sintática do texto, ou como criar um código intermediário que o interpretador possa executar, etc)

Comment: [Este artigo do CodeProject ensina a criar um interpretador em .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/220042/Easily-Create-Your-Own-Parser). Ele basicamente é feito usando muita expressão regular. Indo mais fundo na dor, [há este manual que ensina a criar uma linguagem de programação](http://nathansuniversity.com/). Ainda não substitui um curso de compiladores, mas é um começo.

Comment: Essa técnica de usar expressões regulares para transformar uma linguagem em outra é simples, mas surpreendentemente poderosa! O projeto [processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) (do John Resig, autor do jQuery) por exemplo conseguiu portar a linguagem [Processing](https://processing.org/) para JavaScript simplesmente [usando uma série de regexes para traduzir uma linguagem pra outra](http://ejohn.org/blog/processingjs/), na sua primeira versão pelo menos, e então fazendo a interpretação de fato (usando Canvas).

Comment: É verdade. Tive muito sobre expressão regular numa matéria chamada Teoria da Computação. Era a introdução para Compiladores.

Comment: Depende, você pode criar um interpretador pra uma linguagem que rode em um webbrowser como nesta resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5358/3635 -- No entanto se quer criar um "linguagem" que compile ou interprete sem o browser, será necessário um outra linguagem primeiro, por exemplo c++ e você então irá criar um executável que irá fazer um "parse" na teu script (com linguagem inventada por ti) e irá executar ou compilar e depois executar :)

Comment: Pena que às vezes a pessoa pergunta, some, e recebe feedback quase que imediato que fica sem resposta... @Math, não seria o caso de chuchar diretamente essa tag e tirar aquela sopa que só aumenta a confusão? :)

Comment: @brasofilo hecho

Answer (score 5):

Há uns anos atrás eu precisei permitir que o usuário configurasse espécies de rótulos.

Basicamente ele escrevia um texto mais ou menos assim:

```
    Valor medido: {valor_medido}, Valor considerado: {valor_medido * 0.9}
    Data da medição: {formatar(data_medicao, "dd/mm/aaaa")}
```

Enfim, usando variáveis do sistema e funções previamente definidas, ele configurava diversos rótulos para serem usados em situações específicas, e no final o sistema imprimia algo como:

```
    Valor medido: 80, Valor considerado: 72
    Data da medição: 23/09/2015
```

Os recursos eram bastante amplos: formatação de datas e números, informações condicionais (usando **if**), etc.

No final, acabamos entregando um verdadeiro interpretador de linguagem de programação, embora tenhamos feito muito pouco por conta própria.

Para implementar este recurso, usamos o projeto [ANTLR](http://www.antlr3.org/), e como ponto de partida usamos o projeto [State of the Art Expression Evaluation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18880/State-of-the-Art-Expression-Evaluation) (que usa o ANTLR).

Em poucas palavras, o **ANTLR** lê uma definição de linguagem escrita em **Backus-Naur Form (BNF)** e gera um parser para códigos escritos naquela linguagem.

O parser gerado então é capaz de interpretar um código e entregar uma árvore de objetos (espécie de tokens) que descreve o código interpretado. E então você percorre a árvore e vai executando o que foi determinado pelo código que você acabou de interpretar.

Estes dois projetos que linkei devem te ensinar muito sobre interpretadores de linguagem de programação.

Comment: A pergunta é ampla demais e não pretendi respondê-la integralmente, mas achei que valia a pena uma referência a estes projetos tão valiosos que têm muito a ensinar.

Comment: Achei a pergunta ótima, pena que exige algum trabalho pra ser pertinente pro site.