# Onde eu adiciono os calculos ".py" na página HTML?

Tags: html, python

Fala galera! blz? 
Eu estou começando na área e estou com várias dúvidas. Montei uma página básica de teste HTML e queria inserir um código python que criei (calculo de teste).

Onde e como eu faço esse link entre o HTML e o código .py?

Valeu pela ajuda.

Comment: Vc teria que usar um framework python pra web, sugiro começar com o [Flask](https://www.fullstackpython.com/flask.html) ou mesmo o [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/3.0/)

Comment: Mais um webframework python que voce pode tentar é o [cherrypy](https://cherrypy.org/)

Answer (score 3):

Scripts Python não rodam diretamente no "frontend" e mesmo que alguém diga que é possivel, não será de fato o que ocorreu, o que pode ser no máximo é que executou algo como da resposta do @utluiz:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5358/3635

Neste caso ele usou o https://brython.info/, **mas isso nem chega a ser python de verdade**, é apenas um "interpretador" que se aproxima bastante.

O que você precisa entender é que navegadores interpretam NATIVAMENTE apenas:

- HTML
- XML variados (SVG por exemplo, as vezes dependendo de algum plugin)
- css
- JavaScript
- Tem codec para alguns formatos de imagens, vídeo e áudios
- Alguns outros como "legendas"

E cada navegador tem o seu próprio interpretador de cada coisa

Se deseja usar Python de verdade e não coisas como Berry ou alguma implementação com `XMLHttpRequest` para simular o que precisa entender é aonde esta o seu navegador e aonde esta o seu servidor, resumindo precisa entender o mínimo do que é o HTTP e como seu navegador se comunica com isto, no começo (APENAS NO COMEÇO) desta resposta eu já fiz a introdução de como funciona a comunicação navegador e servidor:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168915/3635

Digo isto porque citaram nos comentários e na outra resposta coisas como Flask e Cherrypy, não adianta muito só citar eles, porque a maioria das pessoas nem entende HTTP direito, incrivelmente tem muita gente que acha que é só chegar e ler uma resposta ou artigo e acha que vai dominar o básico de um conceito, protocolo ou tecnologia, não é assim, na verdade muita coisa dependerá de pratica, o que leva tempo, e mesmo com a minha resposta aqui não vai dominar o básico de verdade, mas ao menos vai entender aonde está o seu navegador e aonde esta o servidor, que é o que importa **PRA COMEÇAR**.

Voltando ao Flask e Cherrypy e qualquer outro framework web, sem entender o que é HTTP ou aonde esta front-end e back-end então nem tem como prosseguir, se leu a resposta que linkei então provavelmente entendeu o básico, então vamos aos pontos, ao criar algo com Flask e "hostear", algo como:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return '<b>Hello</b>'
```

Ao acessar o endereço local (em um teste localhost) vai ser efetuado um DOWNLOAD do conteudo para o seu computador, algo como:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 17 Mar 2020 11:28:53 GMT
Content-Length: 12
Content-Type: text/html

<b>Teste<b/>
```

Note que por padrão ele retornou `Content-Type: text/html` e o navegador vai ASSUMIR que tem que processar como HTML, isso se chama cabeçalho, e mesmo que o conteudo não correspondesse ao que foi dito no cabeçalho o navegador irá assumir conforme o que foi dito nele, para resumir o PYTHON gerou um HTML, ou seja o Python roda no back-end e o framework escolhido gera o conteudo.

Você poderia até gerar imagens, vídeos e outras coisas e devolver com Flask, isto seria baixado pelo seu navegador e se ele for capaz de processar no navegador ele irá exibir, você "não vê" o download ocorrendo diretamente, mas ele ocorre sempre, qualquer coisa que você acessa na internet é feito o download para o seu computador, fique ele na "memória" ou gravado em cache

Answer (score 2):

Programas em Python não são, normalmente, adicionados diretamente a uma página HTML - eles podem *Gerar* páginas HTML ou dados que serão renderizados por código em javascript.

VOcê interage com seus programas em Python a partir do terminal, fazendo programas que criem uma interface gráfica, ou programas que geram o HTML completo - preenchendo valores com o uso de templates - você pode dar uma olhada no projeto ["Flask"](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/) para alguns exemplos mais simples de como fazer isso.

Até é possível embutir código Python direto dentro de HTML, como é feito com Javascript, com o uso de projetos alternativos - um deles é o Brython (https://brython.info) - não é a forma que a maioria das pessoas estuda Python, mas pode funcionar se você está com isso em mente.

Mesmo indo pela via do Brython, é importante - vital - que você estude e entenda a relaçao normal de código Python com páginas web.